# Change splash/login screen in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: login, plymouth

How to change splash/login screen/color in Ubuntu 20.10 ?

I have read many posts on how to change splash/login screens (or at least change its purple color) for  versions of Ubuntu prior to 20.10 which is the one I'm running.

I've been able to change the login screen color by changing the background image but changing a background image just to change the background color seems a little overshooting.
is there a simpler way to change just the background color ? (for those of us who don't like purple).

Is there a way to change the splash screen as well ?

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to change the splash screen.

In 20.10 you can change the login screen background with an image (a solid color, in my case) using
https://github.com/thiggy01/change-gdm-background
download, unzip and follow instructions in README file.

To get rid of (or change) the ubuntu logo, just edit the image /usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png

Answer (score 0):

And did this:

```
$ cd /usr/share/backgrounds
$ ll
```

to list content of the folder and got the following:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1240227 мар 19 16:02 warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

was the picture used for the login screen, and I renamed it:

```
$sudo mv warty-final-ubuntu.png warty-final-ubuntu.png.jpg
```

then copied one of the upper images, in my case `Landscape_Photography_Of_Mountains_by_Simon_Berger.jpg`,
as `warty-final-ubuntu.png`

and now I have a good looking screen with mountain view.
Thanks `@Zanna` for the help!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the splah screen (that initial screen after boot and before the login screen), you should install and configure the `plymouth`, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth

You also can download alternative (and fancy themes) from other sources like the GNOME-Look library community, see https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/108

It's a bunch of commands (no gui actually) but it's straightforward.